# html5 login localstorage for days

Tags: javascript, html

Html5 login localstorage for days. This HTML5 Login script uses localstorage to stores users that and everything works fine.
But I need to add one more thing. I want once the user log in for the first time, the app will store the users info in html5
browser for like 30 days, when 30 days elapse, the user will be redirected back to login again. Can someone help me with that?
Thanks.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.send').click(function(){

        var uname=$('#uname').val();
        var pass=$('#pass').val();

        if(uname==""){

            $('.error').effect("bounce",500).fadeIn(400).html('Enter Your Username');

        }

        else if(pass==""){

            $('.error').effect("bounce",500).fadeIn(400).html('Enter your password');

        }

        else{


            $('.error').hide();
            var userdata= "uname="+uname+"&pass="+pass;


            window.localStorage["uname"] = uname;
            window.localStorage["pass"] = pass;

            $("#loader").show();
            $("#loader").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">Checking your details</span>');

            $.ajax({

                type:"post",
                data:userdata,
                url:"http://localhost/login.php",
                cache:false,
                success:function(msg){

                    $("#loader").hide();
                    $('.error').fadeIn(200).html(msg);

                }

            });



        }
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: You're only showing code for the login form submission on the client side (javascript), so it's difficult to give you a full code example for a solution. One thing you should do is add `window.localStorage["lastSuccessfulLogin"] = new Date();` in your success function for the login. This would set the current date. Then you would check that in whatever part of your code you're using to check if the user is currently logged in.

Comment: Did you ever sort it out? Did you see the update to my answer (I fixed the code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) localstorage data won't expire like cookie. it will stay like it for years.
2) if you want to set expiration date add expiration date as value to localstorage then retrieve this info every time and check you condition like number of days, or hours, or months.
or
3) use cookie where you can set expiration date.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set when the data is set in the localStorage (via another variable in it), and each time the app loads, check for that value and compare it with the current date/time.

Comment: @mason81, just saw your comment basically saying the same thing half an hour ago. Why don't you write it as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to be stealing your answer.

Comment: I appreciate that Shomz. I submitted an answer, it's pretty ugly, but hopefully it gets the point across sufficiently.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment (and Shomz mentioned in his answer), you need to set the current date in the local storage just as you store the username and password (are you sure you need to store the password in local storage -- doesn't seem necessary) and then check if that value is set and compare it to the current date.

Update: fixing the code (forgot to convert the local storage date from a string back to a date object, plus I had a missing close bracket, oops!).

jsfiddle with an example usage: http://jsfiddle.net/uqpywLv3/17/

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.send').click(function(){

        var uname=$('#uname').val();
        var pass=$('#pass').val();

        if(uname==""){
            $('.error').effect("bounce",500).fadeIn(400).html('Enter Your Username');
        }

        else if(pass==""){
            $('.error').effect("bounce",500).fadeIn(400).html('Enter your password');
        }

        else{
            $('.error').hide();
            var userdata= "uname="+uname+"&pass="+pass;

            window.localStorage["uname"] = uname;
            window.localStorage["pass"] = pass;
            // is storing the password this necessary?

            $("#loader").show();
            $("#loader").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">Checking your details</span>');

            $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                data:userdata,
                url:"http://localhost/login.php",
                cache:false,
                success:function(msg){
                    // store the current date
                    window.localStorage["ldate"] = new Date();

                    $("#loader").hide();
                    $('.error').fadeIn(200).html(msg);
                }
            });
        }
    }); // end .send click handler

    // check if the user is logged in
    if (typeof window.localStorage["ldate"] != "undefined") {

        // localstorage seems to store the date as a string
        // so convert it to a date object
        var memDate = new Date(window.localStorage["ldate"]);

        var expDate = new Date(); // current date.
        expDate.setDate(-30); // set to 30 days ago.

        if (memDate > expDate) {
            // user's last login still valid
            // do whatever you think is appropriate here
        } else {
            // user's last login was past 30 days ago
            // perhaps call function to log them out on server side
            // and show login form?
        }
    } else {
        // the user is not logged in.
        // put your code for showing the login form here
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: its not working. submit button is no longer clickable. any further help

Comment: @Sectona -- It's difficult to know for sure without seeing more of your code (and how you chose to implement the inner blocks of the conditionals at the bottom). Are you getting any messages in the console (ex: test in Chrome and use Ctrl+Shift+J)? The only thing I changed with your click handler for the send button was to add `window.localStorage["ldate"] = new Date();` to the success function of your ajax call. I don't think that would hurt anything.

Comment: @Sectona I updated my answer. I was missing a closing bracket and forgot to convert the local storage date back to a date object (it's stored as a string). I also added a jsfiddle example for you to test with. It's really ugly though, sorry.